# Can not upload any file in open cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I have been working on open cart perfectly and just about now I found out I can not upload an avatar or products image(s) via my front end, I can upload or edit products images from back-end for sellers. When a customer from front end tries to upload an avatar or product files, an error message of `"File upload error"`  comes up after a few seconds. Please can someone walk me through on where to verify if the codes are okay?

I did check my host folders (permissions are granted to 0755) I even tried 777 and other tutorial I found on Google search .. but all to no avail.

Comment: are you using a plugin from which the user can upload image from front end..?

Comment: really? all i have is multimerch . how am i suppose to do that?

Comment: i possibly believe that there is file restriction on the file type that can be uploaded ..

Comment: i tried jpeg, png, ico   5kb- 2mb but all to no avail :(